# Android Studio: Failed to initialize editor | Dolphin 2021.3.1

Tags: android-studio

AS: Dolphin | 2021.3.1
Kotlin plugin: 1.7.10
Android Gradle Plugin: 7.0.4
Gradle: 7.1.1
Gradle JDK: version 11.0.13

I've upgraded my Android Studio to **Dolphin 2021.3.1** from **Chipmunk 2021.2.1** and after updating Android Studio I'm facing issue that my project is showing error "**Failed to initialize editor**" in all my xml files.

I've tried the following:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- Clean > Rebuild
- Clean > Rebuild > Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Sync Project with Gradle Files > Clean > Rebuild

But nothing helped me out!

Answer (score 13):

I have same issue with dolphin android studio.
In my case, I have upgraded the project AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) and then restart the android studio.

Problem Solved.

**Recommended:**
downgrade android studio to ***Chipmunk***. If you don't want to upgrade AGP.

Comment: Finally, this solution saved me! I upgraded AGP and it redownloaded Gradle things.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Please Follow these Steps:**

**Solution 1:**

> To Solve failed to initialize the editor in android studio You need to
> update Android Gradle Plugin. First of all, Open your File -> Project
> Structure ( Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S ) -> Project Then You need to
> update Android Gradle Plugin Version to 7.3.0 and Gradle Version to
> 7.4. And then You need to invalidate the cache and restart your IDE will resolve your error.

**In build.gradle : Project Level**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
}
```

**In gradle-wrapper.properties :**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**Solution 2:**

> To Solve failed to initialize editor in android studio You can also
> Repair Your IDE By Click on File -> Repair Your IDE… This will resolve
> your error and now you can see the android layout without facing the
> error. Thanks.

**Solution 3:**

> You can downgrade android studio to Chipmunk. If you don't want
> to upgrade Android Gradle Plugin ( Which I tell in solution 1 above).

Answer (score 2):

**For you that because of others dependencies cannot update the Android Gradle Plugin:**

You'll have to wait a little bit, the devs are already aware. There should eventually be a version to correct this.

For now what you can do to keep working is downgrading the Android Studio Version to [*Chipmunk | 2021.2.1*](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)